# How to calculate AWS RDS Data Transfer Pricing

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I'm looking into the possibility of switching my database to Amazon's RDS offering.

At the moment it is just MySQL installed on a normal LEMP server along with everything else the application needs to run.

While the pricing for RDS instances is clear, I can see there is pricing for data transfer out to the internet of $0.090 per GB.

Presumably this includes query results.

But I have no idea how many bytes my query results are, or how many I might use in a day. Therefore I have no idea how much switching to RDS might actually cost.

Is there any way to calculate this?

This may very well be a stupid question but I'd hate to be stung by a huge fee because I didn't fully understand the costs involved.

Comment: If your application is running inside AWS using VPC, then under normal operating conditions, nothing between your application and your database would be considered data "out to the Internet."  Your application typically sends data to the Internet -- not RDS.  Please clarify your topology.

Comment: Sorry the application itself would stay on a digital ocean lemp server, so any database queries would be going over the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, AWS does not charge for the query output of RDS Database of MySQL engine, but it charges for Aurora Engine.

Comment: I'm afraid your experience has given you some misinformation.  The Aurora cluster volume (which is not EBS) [has a usage charge per 1M I/O](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/pricing/) but I believe there is no documented reason to justify this answer in its current form.

Comment: @Michael, I am also mentioning about Usage charges per 1 M I/O which is not charged for MySQL.